# Compiler error - is private within this context - Line 31

Tags: c++, class, private

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Item{
    private:
        string type;
        string abbrv;
        string uID;
        int aircraft;
        double weight;
        string destination;
    public:
        void print(){
        cout << "ULD: " << type << endl;
        cout << "Abbreviation: " << abbrv << endl;
        cout << "ULD-ID: " << uID << endl;
        cout << "Aircraft: " << aircraft << endl;
        cout << "Weight: " << weight << " Kilograms" << endl;
        cout << "Destination: " << destination << endl;
   }

    friend void kilotopound(Item);
};
void kilotopound(Item I){
    cout << "Weight in Pounds: " << I.weight * 2.2 << " LBS " << endl;
}

int main(){
   Item I;
   I.type = "Container";
   I.uID = "AYK68943IB";
   I.abbrv = "AYK";
   I.aircraft = 737;
   I.weight = 1654;
   I.destination = "PDX";
   I.print();
   kilotopound(I);

   return 0;
}
```

Starting on line 31 I'm getting the error 'std::__cxxll::string Item::type' is private within this context

I'm basically trying to make the data private from this code

```
class Item{
    public:
        string type;
        string abbrv;
        string uID;
        int aircraft;
        double weight;
        string destination;
    void print(){
        cout << "ULD: " << type << endl;
        cout << "Abbreviation: " << abbrv << endl;
        cout << "ULD-ID: " << uID << endl;
        cout << "Aircraft: " << aircraft << endl;
        cout << "Weight: " << weight << " Kilograms" << endl;
        cout << "Destination: " << destination << endl;
   }

    friend void kilotopound(Item);
};
void kilotopound(Item I){
    cout << "Weight in Pounds: " << I.weight * 2.2 << " LBS " << endl;
}

int main(){
   Item I;
   I.type = "Container";
   I.uID = "AYK68943IB";
   I.abbrv = "AYK";
   I.aircraft = 737;
   I.weight = 1654;
   I.destination = "PDX";
   I.print();
   kilotopound(I);

   return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm just sort of lost on how I can resolve the error. Thanks!

Also I need to be able to copy and output the copied data once again if anyone can help with that as well, with private data too. Thanks again!

Comment: To save everyone the trouble of counting, please point out which line is line 31. I think it's this one: `I.type = "Container";`

Comment: The purpose of `private` is to make it so that nothing outside the class, for example `main`, can access the members. Why do you want the members to be `private` if you also want to access them outside the class?

Comment: Your problem is that `main()` cannot access private members of your class.    Instead of trying to assign directly to private class members, add public member functions (called setters and getters) that can set or get the underlying private data.   And provide constructors that can be used to initialise members when creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Item{
    private:
        string type;
        string abbrv;
        string uID;
        int aircraft;
        double weight;
        string destination;
    public:
        Item(string t, string a, string u, int aC, double w, string d){
            type = t;
            abbrv = a;
            uID = u;
            aircraft = aC;
            weight = w;
            destination = d;
        }
        void print() {
          cout << "ULD: " << type << endl;
          cout << "Abbreviation: " << abbrv << endl;
          cout << "ULD-ID: " << uID << endl;
          cout << "Aircraft: " << aircraft << endl;
          cout << "Weight: " << weight << " Kilograms" << endl;
          cout << "Destination: " << destination << endl;
        }

    friend void kilotopound(Item);
};

void kilotopound(Item I){
    cout << "Weight in Pounds: " << I.weight * 2.2 << " LBS " << endl;
}

int main(){
   Item I ("Container", "AYK68943IB", "AYK", 737, 1654, "PDX");
   I.print();
   kilotopound(I);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it!